# How to Configure QT Environment to work with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt4

Could you please help me how to make QT work in VS2010? step by step please :)

i installed a fresh copy of windows and i have this files:

1. Windows 7 Ultimate
2. Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
3. qt-win-opensource-4.7.3-vs2008
4. qt-vs-addin-1.1.9

Also i'm really confused, i found many ways to do this but all didn't work. Also i don't know why some download "qt-win-opensource-4.7.3-vs2008" and then recompile it. Dose "qt-vs-addin-1.1.9" replace the recompiling step or what?

So please i need a help on how to install QT with VS 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vs-addin does not replace recompiling but there's no need to recompile if you have pre-built Qt binaries (unless you want to change the configuration).

First install your pre-built binary package of Qt. If you've chosen to rebuild it, do that (you won't use the VS UI for this, it's all command-line based). Be sure you install this to a path that doesn't include any spaces in it... something like C:\qt\qt-4.7.3 perhaps.

Then install vs-addin, and start VS.

Now open the Qt menu, go to Qt options, and click Add to add a version. (You can install multiple Qt versions on your system this way if you wish.) Give the version a name of your own choosing, and specify the path to where you've installed it. Close out the options dialog.

Finally, create a new project and notice that the creation wizard has a section for Qt4 Project templates. Choose Qt application and you're well along your way.

Comment: Thank you mah for replying
i downloaded this version of QT (http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008)

and i installed it and also installed VS-addin and it automatically add me the version in QT menu with any interruption from me.

i created a project and i compiled it and it works fine but i found a problem when i tried to open the exe file produced it gave me error (the program can't start because QtCored4.dll is missing from your computer) i downloaded it and installed another required dll and finally it gave me this error
http://i.imgur.com/JrXxD.png

Comment: @Amr Ramadan - sorry for my late response, I only just saw your message. The library you mention is the debug version of the DLL (QtCore<b>d</b>4.dll), and it's likely not found on your path. Extend your PATH environment variable to pick it up (or build a non-debug version and ensure the non-debug DLLs are on your path) and you will be ok.